# Custom post type permalink is doesn't show in admin

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks

I have problem with custom post type - permalink is doesn't show:

[image]

Post type is published, but I can't it show on website.
I tried change permalink structure to `?p=123`, but it still doesn't work. I tried change 'rewrite' attribute in code to false, but no difference.

**Some ideas where can be problem?**

Here is my code for custom post types:

```
$args_team = array(
    'labels' => sk_post_type_labels( __('Tým', 'sk'), __('Tým', 'sk') ),
    'public' => true,
    'has_archive' => true,
    'exclude_from_search' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'menu_position' => 10,
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'team' ),
    'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail','page-attributes')
);
```

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: Please [check this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-post-types/) to generate custom post types. Use this plugin instead of doing a code. This may help you.

Answer (score 5):

I set the following to true to display the permalinks in the admin section.

```
'publicly_queryable' => true,
```

Comment: I found you also need to set `'public' => true`

Comment: Actually, `'publicly_queryable' => true` doesn't have any effect on this. You must set `'public' => true`.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing *exclude from search* and set your permalinks to **Post name**.

you should be able to access with: mysite.com/team/new-team-member